# How to render individual object within array after fetching data from API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-maps, react-hooks

i'm trying to map out the individual driver from the JSON array I've generated. But i cant seem to be able to map it into a list or anything.

JSON:

```
[{"driver_id":"0-ikkpyhyjg9","location":{"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"bearing":229}},{"driver_id":"1-fk8jgaw8m7m","location":{"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"bearing":306}},{"driver_id":"2-w93e6x4hj7n","location":{"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"bearing":353}}]
```

react hooks:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/drivers', {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                data => {
                    setIsLoading(true)
                    setDrivers(data.drivers)
                    console.log(data.drivers)
                },
                error => {
                    setIsLoading(true)
                    setError(error)
                    console.log(error.message)
                }
            )
    }, [])
```

I would ideally want to be able to render as a marker on an interface like google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even try to render the code. It needs a `return(...)`  at the end, in which you put your html. And you should do `setDrivers(data)`, because otherwise you go in one layer too deep (which does not even exist). Your return would probaby looks something like this:

```
return (
   <div>
      { drivers.map((driver) =>
         <h2>{driver.driver_id}</h2>
         {/* And whatever else you want to show */}
      }
   </div>
)
```